# How to add entries to my map without overwrite existing with a fallback in case of empty

Tags: arrays, dictionary, groovy

I'm trying to create a map from a list of files that changed in our SCM,
So far I've managed to get the list of the changed files(in the code below I put hard-coded example )
and then map them to the relevant services which I want to build.
I also added the fallback in case the path is not mapped in the "path2component" function.

My problem is that the map that I'm creating is always overriding itself,
and not inserting the entries one after the other as expected.

```
ChangedFilesList = [main/exporter/pom.xml, main/app/download-server/pom.xml]

ChangedFilesList.each {
    println "Changes in file: ${it}"
    def file = "${it}"
    triggermap = path2component.findAll{  // find relevant map entries
        file.find(it.key)
    }.collectEntries{ // build your map
        ["trigger-${it.value}", true]
    } ?: ["trigger-none": true] // provide a fallback
    println "triggermap:" + triggermap
}
```

***My output is this:***

```
Changes in file: main/app/download-server/pom.xml
triggermap:[trigger-download-server:true]
Changes in file: main/exporter/pom.xml
triggermap:[trigger-rest-exporter:true]
```

***Expected output:***

```
Changes in file: main/app/download-server/pom.xml
triggermap:[trigger-download-server:true]
Changes in file: main/exporter/pom.xml
triggermap:[trigger-download-server:true,trigger-rest-exporter:true]
```

Comment: I think the `putIfAbsent` method of `Map` is what you need

Comment: could you also provide the definition (or a mocked version conveying the intent) of `path2component`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code:

```
def changedFiles = ['main/exporter/pom.xml', 'main/app/download-server/pom.xml']

def path2component = [
  'main/exporter':            'rest-exporter', 
  'main/app/download-server': 'download-server'
]

def triggerMap = path2component.findAll { path, service -> 
  changedFiles.any { it.find(path) }
}.collectEntries { path, service -> 
  ["trigger-${service}".toString(), true]
}.withDefault { false }

println triggerMap
println("rest-exporter:     ${triggerMap['trigger-rest-exporter']}")
println("unchanged-service: ${triggerMap['trigger-unchanged-service']}")
```

uses the groovy map [withDefault](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#withDefault(groovy.lang.Closure)) construct to specify a value which should be returned if a key is not found in the map. This code tries to mock your scenario with a `path2component` map. Result of running the above:

```
─➤ groovy solution.groovy

[trigger-rest-exporter:true, trigger-download-server:true]
rest-exporter:     true
unchanged-service: false
```

However if they only thing you want to do is figure out if a service needs rebuilding, there is really no need to have the 'trigger-' prefix in there:

```
def simplerMap = path2component.findAll { path, service -> 
  changedFiles.any { it.find(path) }
}.collectEntries { path, service -> 
  [service, true]
}.withDefault { false }

println simplerMap
println("rest-exporter:     ${simplerMap['rest-exporter']}")
println("unchanged-service: ${simplerMap['unchanged-service']}")
```

which prints:

```
─➤ groovy solution.groovy

[rest-exporter:true, download-server:true]
rest-exporter:     true
unchanged-service: false
```

and if you don't have millions of items in this trigger map (i.e. performance is not an issue), you could also just do:

```
def changedServices = path2component.findAll { path, service -> 
  changedFiles.any { it.find(path) }
}.values()

println changedServices
println("rest-exporter:     ${changedServices.contains('rest-exporter')}")
println("unchanged-service: ${changedServices.contains('unchanged-service')}")
```

which prints:

```
─➤ groovy solution.groovy

[rest-exporter, download-server]
rest-exporter:     true
unchanged-service: false
```

Answer (score 0):

Groovy provides variant of `get`, that lets you provide a fallback, which also get's written into the map.  E.g.:

```
def m = [a: true]
assert m.get("b", false)==false
assert m.containsKey("b")
```

Yet, the absence of a key with a regular `get` will give you `null`, which is basically `false`